# Regex to get last word in URL between / and /

Tags: javascript

How do I get the last word in a URL that is URL between / and / ?

For example:

http://mywebsite.com/extractMe/test

http://mywebsite.com/extractMe

http://mywebsite.com/settings/extractMe/test

http://mywebsite.com/settings/extractMe

Here I would want to get `extractMe` from the URL.

Answer (score 3):

If the URL is consistent, why not just use:

```
// Option 1
var url = "http://mywebsite.com/extractMe/test";
var extractedText = url.split("/")[3];

​// Option 2
// If when a trailing slash is present you want to return "test", use this code
var url = "http://mywebsite.com/extractMe/test/";
var urlAry = url.split("/");
var extractedText = urlAry[urlAry.length - 2];

​// Option 3
// If when a trailing slash is present you want to return "extractMe", use this:
var url = "http://mywebsite.com/extractMe/test/";
var urlAry = url.split("/");
var positionModifier = (url.charAt(url.length-1) == "/") ? 3 : 2;    
var extractedText = urlAry[urlAry.length - positionModifier];
```

Here's a working fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/JamesHill/Arj9B/

Comment: How do you know if extractMe is the last, second last etc.?

Comment: @Cranio, how do you know it's not? Please read my answer. `If the URL is consistent...`

Comment: The second example answers the question. The last word that is in between two slashes

Comment: @Cranio, Just relax a bit...geesh. I've updated option 2 to allow for a trailing slash.

Comment: I'm all the way relaxed. Already deleted my comment as I found ME wrong. Sorry.

Comment: @james, you shouldn't.. per the OP instuctions if there was a trailing slash, you should return `test`..

Comment: This is getting intense. I updated option to to allow for both interpretations of the requirements.

Answer (score 1):

it works with / or without it in the end :)

```
var url = "http://mywebsite.com/extractMe/test/";    
var m = url.match(/\/([^\/]+)[\/]?$/);

console.log(m[1]);
```

output:
test

Answer (score 0):

This accounts BOTH for URLS like `http://mywebsite.com/extractMe/test` and `http://mywebsite.com/extractMe/`

```
function processUrl(url)
{
    var tk = url.split('/');
    var n = tk.length;
    return tk[n-2];
}
```

**Edited.**

Comment: So that's the same now what James originally had ;)

Comment: @FelixKling James made an edit, it was not like mine before. Now it's indeed the same.

Answer (score 0):

Regular Expression way:

```
var str = "http://example.com/extractMe/test";
var match = str.match(/\/([^\/]+)\/[^\/]+$/);

if (match) {
    console.log(match[1]);
}
```